# 2-D lookup table when breakpoints arent increasing

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have three tables:

```
z=                      x=           y=
    [18,16,12;    [5,5,5;       [30,60,85;
    40,37,33;    10,10,10       30,60,85;
    82,79,75]     20,20,20]      30,60,85;]
```

where z=F(x,y)

So I can use 2-D Lookup Table to find Z if I use X - (5,10,20) and Y - (30,60,85) as breakpoints.

But now I want to find values for Y by using Z and X as breakpoints, how can I do this in simulink

Comment: Mathematically there isn't a unique mapping from (x,z) to y.  What do you expect to happen if there are multiple possible answers?

Comment: @PhilGoddard I believe there is. Can you give and example where you think that isnt the case?

Comment: In general there will not be a 1-1 mapping.  I was assuming that the small data set you give is just a sample of a larger set.  It does appear that for the above specific data set that there is a 1-1 mapping.  I suspect the easiest way using the above data would be to literally fit the equation of a plane (i.e. ax*by+cz=d) to each of the 4 planes mapped out by the data and use the appropriate one of those four equations depending on the x and z data.